# Having different chances to pick a name

Tags: python, random

I am writing a program for work where I am pulling two names from a .txt document. I have written a program that will grab the names but I need to change it so that I can give each name a probability of being chosen. This probability will change as I do audits. How could I do this in Python? I am attaching the code that I have made so far but I have no idea how to make it have different probabilities.

```
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/Lance/Documents/Teams')
with open('San_Diego.txt') as taf:
    data = taf.readline()
San_Diego = data.strip().split(',')
with open('OCIE.txt') as oaf:
    data = oaf.readline()
OCIE = data.strip().split(',')   
def picker(seq):
    from functools import partial
    from random import choice
    return partial(choice, seq)
team_picker = picker(San_Diego)
print([team_picker() for c in range(2)])
team_picker = picker(OCIE)
print([team_picker() for c in range(2)])
```

Comment: This might the most poorly formatted question ever. Please consider revising it a bit... and just maybe add a few more tags than "random".

Comment: Please specify what language or development environment you are using.  It would be best if you post the code you've tried (or try something first) and then post the specific problem or error you have.

Answer (score 5):

Given two names **jack** and **jill**, with a respective weight of 0.25 and 0.75, here's a solution using the [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/) package to select 5 weighted random names:

```
import numpy

names = ['jack', 'jill']
weights = [0.25, 0.75]
bins = numpy.add.accumulate(weights)
selected_indexes = numpy.digitize(numpy.random.random_sample(5), bins)

print numpy.array(names)[selected_indexes]
```

Executing this three times, I get the following output:

```
['jill' 'jack' 'jill' 'jill' 'jill']
['jack' 'jill' 'jill' 'jack' 'jill']
['jill' 'jill' 'jill' 'jill' 'jill']
```

Comment: @AlexGreg Yeah :-) Now need a lot of votes to get that [Reversal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) badge :-)

Comment: Rats, the question has been changed. Now my answer is no longer valid.

Comment: Haha yeah sorry. I really didn't explain that well

Comment: @southpoleelf To make your question qualify as a good question according to SO standards, now you would have to show what you already tried, preferably with some source code.